# Checking correctness of "Books is not my thing."

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to say:

> Books is not my thing.

I know I could also say I don't like books or I'm not interested in them, But, If I wanna say this way, Can I say this? Or I should say:

> Books are not my things.

Please clear this doubt!

Comment: I would prefer "Reading books is not my thing", referring to the action rather than the object. Unless the books themselves are causing a problem, that is.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to say this is

> Books are not my thing.

Note that this is partially slang, and so the normal rules of grammar are less rigidly enforced.

"Thing", in this context, is a slang term that indicates either a)expertise or specialization or b) interest, in the indicated subject. Basically, if X is "my thing" than either I am good at X or I enjoy X (or both). One's "thing" can also indicate responsibility for a project or undertaking (especially in a business context). E.g. "Don't ask me about XYZ that is broken, I haven't worked on it. That is Bob's thing."

So this phrase means "I'm not very interested in (reading) books".

Comment: Which normal rules of grammar have you enforced less rigidly in that sentence?

Comment: @userr2684291 Normally, the subject and object will agree in number. Compare the OP's second quotation: "(These) books are not my things" would generally not be slang, and would generally be interpreted as a disavowal of ownership over the indicated books. For an exception that illustrates this point, see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17212/number-agreement-between-subject-and-object

Comment: While I have no quibble with any of the above, there are occasional exceptions to the singular/plural rules when an apparent plural noun is considered as a single concept, as in: Mathematics/statistics is not my thing!

Comment: @sharur For starters, *my thing* isn't an object; it's just a predicative complement. "Normally, the subject and object will agree in number" – this is also wrong (e.g., ***He** eats **cakes**.* is perfectly grammatical and *normal*). You might be conflating it with *subject-verb agreement* which says that a subject and a verb must agree in number (e.g., ***He eat** cakes.* is ungrammatical). There's no such rule about complements (subject and predicative complement). Consider the following neutral/informal utterance: *They are a couple.* – again, the complements don't agree in number.

Comment: See *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston and Pullum, pp.512–3 *No agreement of number*.